# how to show the timer in incrementing way in android text view

Tags: android, timer

I am new to Android. In my application I have a TextView and within it I want to show the time ticking in this way:

`00:01 ticking 00:02...`

something like that, ticking every second as time increases. I have got decreasing time but not many examples on increasing.

Comment: use timer and call the function for every second..

Comment: how to do this sir please can u explain me with code or any links will be help full sir

Answer (score 1):

initialize a long value with the starting interval of countdown and  inside `onTick()` **substract** this with remaining time.

Comment: please explain in it with the help of some code .it will good to understande. please post the code

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution to increment the count down timer for every second click on https://stackoverflow.com/a/15878178/2257398

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged (links tend to get stale over time).
Please consider editing your answer and adding a synopsis here.